# Rails: How to process a file that was sent with curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, file-upload, curl

I'm trying to create a restful api capable of receiving a file. 
http://leejava.wordpress.com/2009/07/30/upload-file-from-rest-in-ruy-on-rail-with-json-format/
talks of how to accomplish this simply.

Not being very used to rails or curl, I don't know how to formulate my curl call.
Could anyone help me.  Explain how to use curl to send a file, and how to use rails to accept and store the file. 
Note.. the file is a 10 meg zip file.  For testing I called it. 
C:\test.zip..

I've looked at tutorials, but they all seem to be web page based. They also all degrade to resizing pictures.. Like uploading and presenting images are the same topic.

Comment: What are you using to store the file? CarrierWave or Paperclip?

Answer (score 5):

You need to know a bit about how your server-side is expecting the data.  If it is a http POST with multipart/form-data (which I think it is), then this will probably help:

```
curl  -F "fileParam=@c:\test.zip" -F "param1=xxx" -F "param2=yyyy" http://my.server/post-service
```

This will use curl to post form-data (including a file) to the given url with the given parameters.  You need to know the parameter names for the file and the other optional parameters, and you have to obviously get the URL correct to reach your service.

Hope that helps.

Comment: right now, there is no service.. I'm writing both sides.  I don't care how, as long as rails can get an process a file that I send it.  Thanks I think your answer is the one

Comment: If I followed this site to the letter, could you guess at what the params would be?  http://over9000.org/rails/saving-ruby-on-rails-attachments-as-blobs

Comment: This helped me out a bunch with testing an API with a carrierwave upload controller. THX